# Creating a body font rule for iOS and Android

Tags: android, ios, css, phonegap-build

In a Phonegap App would this rule display the body copy in the native system font?

```
body
{
font-family: -apple-system, "Roboto", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}
```

On iOS the rule above would display `-apple-system` (San Fransisco) and fall back to Helvetica

On Android it wouldnt know `-apple-system` so fall back to Roboto the system font or again fall back to `Helvetica`

Answer (score 1):

@MarkL
font control on Android is not that good. Unlike Apple, which controls every aspect of the mobile device. Google allows manufactures to do whatever they want - within reason. Google ships a base set of fonts with all devices, but a manufactures often get new fonts - because they are relatively inexpensive. Your best work-around is to import fonts - Either SVG or true-type or similar fonts.

NOTE: store these fonts on the mobile device for best performance. Do not get the fonts from the internet or you app have problems. Best of Luck

Comment: Yeah I thought that would be the case. The client is happy with Helvetica as a base font if all else fails. I just thought the code above would have enough fall backs and was in the correct order? 

On my iphone the app displays the San Fransisco fine so its applying the font rule properly but I've not tested in Android yet - I was hoping it would ignore -apple-system and use Roboto instead, and if it didnt have that fall back to Helvetica / Arial etc.

Comment: @MarkL another unspoken issue for fonts is the actual display. This has two different factors that affect the final outcome. 1) the acutal DPI (or pixel density) The person that I think [explains this best](http://www.quirksmode.org/blog/archives/2010/04/a_pixel_is_not.html) is PPK. 2) the second issue is the software that drives the webview - which is sometimes webkit. Paul Irish [explains this best.](http://www.paulirish.com/2013/webkit-for-developers/) For me, I often cannot see the minor difference between fonts - unless I magnify. Best of Luck